# How do I use an event-listener inside useEffect?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to move some code from a React Native class component into a Functional Component. The original code looks like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
this.state.broadcastSubscriber = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('event', (intent) =>{ this.broadcastReciever(intent)});
}
```

What I have tried so far is different permutations of:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const broadcastSubscriber = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('event', (intent) =>{ broadcastReciever(intent)});
    }}, []);
```

Including things like making broadcastReciever a useCallback function. So far though broadcastReciever never hears anything outside of when it is first ran in useEffect.

Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

PS: I am aware DeviceEventEmitter is depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
const broadcastReciever = (intent)=>{ //do you intent code here}

useEffect(() => {
  DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('event', broadcastReciever);
  return DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener('event', broadcastReciever);
}}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Event Listener in useEffect like this

```
useEffect(() => {
   
    const loads = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      //do something here on Listner
    });
    return () => {
        loads
    }}, [props.navigation]);
```

Comment: are you sure this dependency is required, props.navigation?

Comment: For navigation event Listeners its require